# antd form field is not resetting for checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a antd form that consists of input and checkboxes.

antd : 4.16.0
react : 17.0.2

After using,

```
this.formRef.current.resetFields();
```

the input fields are getting reset but not the checkboxes.

Sample Code:

```
<Form
            layout="vertical"
            hideRequiredMark
            initialValues={{
              sunH: [
                moment("00:00", "HH:mm"),
                moment("00:00", "HH:mm"),
              ],
              monH: [
                moment("00:00", "HH:mm"),
                moment("00:00", "HH:mm"),
              ],
            }}
            ref={this.props.formRef}
          >
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="pName"
                  label="Name"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "Please enter Name",
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <Input placeholder="Enter name" />
                </Form.Item>

    <Form.Item name="Mon" label="" valuePropName="checked">
                          <Text>Mon</Text>
                        </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
```

the form takes in a onCancel props, so onCancel,

```
this.formRef.current.resetFields();
```

log of this.formRef.current:

[image]

Comment: add your form code, i only found the form.item code in the question

Comment: which version of antd and react you are using?

Comment: @sojin added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manually set radio fields value null in that function ... 
all you have to do is ...

```
            formRef.setFieldsValue(['label_name(Mon)'] : undefined)
```

try  `formRef.current.setFieldsValue` if you cant't change using upper code. 
for functional component you have to take the form reference that is binding using useForm() and you have to call setfield method same.

```
form.setFieldsValue(['label_name(Mon)'] : undefined )
```

Comment: Is the syntax correct ? Im getting error

Comment: `this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue(undefined);` tried this, but still not clearing the checkboxes

Comment: can u give me a log of `this.formRef.current` ?

Comment: Added log in question

Comment: write this and check ...
`this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({['Mon'] : undefined })`

Comment: Doesn't work, tried !

Comment: `this.formRef.current.getFieldsValue()` console.log this code ....
can you please tell me does this code show your form fields value ?

Comment: the log only shows the input field but not the checkbox fields

Comment: can u make a draft of your code in any online code editor like as codesandbox or codepen & give a link in your question ?
I can check out the code then.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/myform-ib0c8   Here once the submit button is clicked, the form shld reset, but resets for input field but not for checkboxes.

Comment: ok.. I have changed some code in your codesandbox project... now its working as you expected ... the problem was there was no name of checkboxes form item . so , form reference state wasn't. handling checkboxes . now I give the form.item a name & change the way you were implementing checkboxes..

                     `<Checkbox.Group options={['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']}  
                     onChange={this.onChange} />`

this way you can pass array of checkboxes value within a single  line of code . 
go check it out on your codesandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/myform-forked-gix93
check the changes of your code here.

Answer (score 1):

[ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-nest-messages](http://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-nest-messages) Check the second example, they have well explained everything you need there

https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-ff1uf?file=/index.js:0-2953

Check this working example with checkbox

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Select, Checkbox } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;
const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 8
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 16
  }
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: {
    offset: 8,
    span: 16
  }
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onGenderChange = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case "male":
        form.setFieldsValue({
          note: "Hi, man!"
        });
        return;

      case "female":
        form.setFieldsValue({
          note: "Hi, lady!"
        });
        return;

      case "other":
        form.setFieldsValue({
          note: "Hi there!"
        });
    }
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    form.resetFields();
  };

  const onFill = () => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      note: "Hello world!",
      gender: "male"
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form {...layout} form={form} name="control-hooks" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item
        name="note"
        label="Note"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="gender"
        label="Gender"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Select
          placeholder="Select a option and change input text above"
          onChange={onGenderChange}
          allowClear
        >
          <Option value="male">male</Option>
          <Option value="female">female</Option>
          <Option value="other">other</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        noStyle
        shouldUpdate={(prevValues, currentValues) =>
          prevValues.gender !== currentValues.gender
        }
      >
        {({ getFieldValue }) =>
          getFieldValue("gender") === "other" ? (
            <Form.Item
              name="customizeGender"
              label="Customize Gender"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true
                }
              ]}
            >
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
          ) : null
        }
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="remember"
        valuePropName="checked"
        wrapperCol={{
          offset: 8,
          span: 16
        }}
      >
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button htmlType="button" onClick={onReset}>
          Reset
        </Button>
        <Button type="link" htmlType="button" onClick={onFill}>
          Fill form
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Nope, the second example doesn't have a checkbox field. My issue is with checkbox field , not the input field.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a sandbox example with checkbox, check this https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-ff1uf?file=/index.js:0-2953

Comment: I'm using class based components , so useForm() hook doesn't help.

Comment: You are using the latest react version right, so the functional component will work perfectly in your project. also React is preferring to use functional components if you are using latest react version

Comment: Yeah, But this is a ongoing project where there is already tons of lines of code written, Changing them for a form would be hectic